# Unique nodes and c#

Tags: c#, xml, dom, xmlnode

Is there a good way in c# to look through an XML node list using DOM and get a node list of only the unique nodes and also a list of each nodes unique possible attributes.

The XMl file in question has nodes of the same name but with different attributes, i want a list of all the possible ones. Also the list of nodes i would like to be only of the unique nodes, rather than having repeats (so node lists i generate at the moment might have contact twice, three time ect within it). And it needs to work for any XML document. Any ideas?

Here is an example:

```
 <book id="bk112">
  <author>Galos, Mike</author> 
  <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title> 
  <genre>Computer</genre> 
  <price>49.95</price> 
  <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date> 
 </book>
 <book id="bk162">
  <genre>fiction</genre> 
  <popularity>High</popularity> 
  <price>20.00</price> 
  <publish_date>2002-03-12</publish_date> 
 </book>
 <cd id="bk162">
  <genre>jaz</genre> 
  <popularity>High</popularity> 
  <price>10.00</price>
 </cd>
```

and get some sort of output like:

```
there are 2 of the type book
there are 1 of the type cd
there are 3 of the type genre 
book may have the attributes author, title, genre, price, popularity, publish_date
```

but in a way that works for any xml file.

In the case of genre it doesnt need to be celver in any way, just know there are 3 genre nodes in the document.

Comment: sample xml and expected output and ofcourse what have you tried?

Comment: See `HtmlAgilityPack`, `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Comment: Could you post an example XML to make your question clearer? What is considered unique? ie. If a contact node appears at different levels of the XML document, is it still a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this do it?

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
List<XElement> distinctDocs = xDoc.Descendants().GroupBy(x => x.Name).Where(x => x.Count() == 1).Select(g => g.Single()).ToList();
```

Comment: Dont think so unless I'm missing something. I don't have the names of the nodes untill runtime

Comment: @user2707220 this solution doesn't require you to have any names at runtime.  Why don't you run it, set a breakpoing, and check what's in the `distinctDocs` var

Comment: @user2707220 I've edited my answer to avoid type confusion.  try it out

Comment: using System.Linq; is ther yet both xDocument and XElement aren't being recognized?

Comment: @user2707220  `using System.Xml.Linq;`

Comment: @user2707220 you can right click on your element and click `resolve` and it will tell you what using statement you need